# Java - How to convert URL to PATH for Files.lines()

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, nio

How to convert a url to path with authentication?

Sample code:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com,";
String userpwd = "userName : password";

Path p = Path.get(url.toString());

Files.lines(p);
```

I achieved to read the url content through Buffer reader, but I wanted to do the same using the above code also.

Comment: The JDK doesn't a HTTP file system provider. So I think what you want to do is open an input stream to the URL, wrap it with a buffered reader and then use BufferedReader::lines.

Comment: Normal input stream and bufferReader works fine. But i am trying to do the same in Java-8 Files. In hope of optimising the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        String url = "https://www.google.com";
        String userpwd = "userName : password";

        Path p = Path.of(URI.create(url));
```

Comment: This does what you ask but you will have to get a provider for the service.

Comment: How to authenticate the path, so that it can be used in nio.Files.line(p) to retrieve the content of the file. I came across 'SmbFile', but that seems similar to io.File.